# How to prevent pass data to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do I prevent sending model to to Controller if form is not validated?

*Razor*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccountName, new { @id = "accountNameText", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Account name" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @id = "accountPasswordText", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="valideLogin()">Login</button>
        </div>
        <span id="loginStatusMessege" style="color: red">

        </span>
    </div>
}
```

*jQuery*

```
function valideLogin() {
    var accName = $('#accountNameText');
    var accPass = $('#accountPasswordText');

    if (accName.val() === '' || accName.val() === '') {
        $('#loginStatusMessege').html('Account name and password cannot be blank.');
    }
}
```

After I press Login Button and textboxes are not filled, code succesfully goes into jQuery and response about the error, but still and everytime I am getting into Controller. How do I prevent this action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding in `return false;`:

```
function valideLogin() {
    var accName = $('#accountNameText');
    var accPass = $('#accountPasswordText');

    if (accName.val() === '' || accName.val() === '') {
        $('#loginStatusMessege').html('Account name and password cannot be blank.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign an identifier to your form the valid it in the submit event handler.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm")){
}
```

Bind the submit event using jQuery, in the event handler use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to cancel the default action of form when condition is not fulfilled.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event){
    var accName = $('#accountNameText');
    var accPass = $('#accountPasswordText');

    if (accName.val() === '' || accName.val() === '') {
        $('#loginStatusMessege').html('Account name and password cannot be blank.');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Comment: :) for suggesting `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`.

Comment: Overall best answer, but you should always use `on` (i.e. `.on('submit', function () { ... }`) rather than the event specific methods like `submit`. The latter are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent using return statement like this :

```
function valideLogin() {
    var accName = $('#accountNameText');
    var accPass = $('#accountPasswordText');

    if (accName.val() === '' || accName.val() === '') {
        $('#loginStatusMessege').html('Account name and password cannot be blank.');
    return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add validation to your code or to use `Ajax.BeginForm`, or both. 
As you are using `Html.BeginForm` this will go straight to the controller and will ignore your jQuery.JavaScript.

You need to look at a good tutorial. For example [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using jQuery/Javascript to validate your form, just consume the form, change up your `valideLogin` function slightly:

```
function valideLogin() {
    var accName = $('#accountNameText');
    var accPass = $('#accountPasswordText');
    return accName.val() !== '' && accPass.val() !== '';
}
```

Then, add a `click` event listener to your submit button like this:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(event) {
    if (!valideLogin()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

What this does is: it consumes your click on the submit button event.

P.S: In your provided code example you check if `accName` is empty twice. Changes that to check `accName` and `accPass` in my example for you.

Comment: Its always better to bind `submit` event with form as you can also submit it by using `enter` key in a textbox, in this scenario your method with never be invoked.

Comment: @Satpal: Here, `click` is bound to the submit button, not the form. The submit button will fire `click` on any activation of the button, whether by an actual mouse click or by pressing enter. However, I do agree it's better to bind to the form's `submit` event, in general, when doing form validation.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery:

```
if (accName.val() === '' || accName.val() === '') {
    $('#loginStatusMessege').html('Account name and password cannot be blank.');
return false;
}
```

In Markup:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="return valideLogin();">Login</button>
```

Here's the code I tested with:

Markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home"))
{
    <div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="return Test();">Login</button>
        </div>
        <span id="loginStatusMessege" style="color: red">

        </span>
    </div>
}
```

Javascript:

```
function Test() {
    return false;
}
```

This will never get to the action in the controller as the Javascript always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `return false;` in the `if` condition, To prevent the call to controller.